# How to read only the last message coming from the server and with a timeout Socket Java

Tags: java, processing, serversocket

I am writing a small game using processing and would like to add a multiplayer feature. I used Socket and have now a problem : I would like to read only the last message from the server and use something that doesn't idle for a server message. Here is the code I used. It is like a level select for the server that send the level chosen to the client so it can load it but on the client, since the server only send a message when a new level is loaded and the client's game just freeze until it recieves a message from the server.

Code for the server :

```
    //Set up all the buttons
    disableMenus();
    enableMenus(7,13);
    enableMenus(19,19);

    //show the current loaded level
    printLevel();
    printGuards(true);
    for(int i = 0 ; i < cams.length ; i++) {
      if(cams[i]) {
        while (camAngleMin[i] > camAngleMax[i]) {
          camAngleMin[i] = camAngleMin[i] - 2*PI;
        }
        int t = 0;
        int r = 0;
        int buffer = round(camAngle[i]/(PI/2));
        PImage images;
        if(buffer > 3)
          buffer = 0;
        else if(buffer < 0)
          buffer = 3;
        images = camImage[buffer];
        if(buffer == 0) {
          t = images.width;
          r = 1;
        } else if(buffer == 1) {
          t = images.width/2;
          r = images.height;
        } else if(buffer == 2) {
          t = 0;
          r = 1;
        } else {
          t = images.width/2;
          r = 0;
        }
        if(camAngle[i] > camAngleMax[i] && camBuffer[i] == 0) {
          camGoToMin[i] = true;
          camBuffer[i] = 200;
        } else if(camAngle[i] < camAngleMin[i] && camBuffer[i] == 0) {
          camGoToMin[i] = false;
          camBuffer[i] = 200;
        } else if(camBuffer[i] > 0){
          camBuffer[i]--;
        }
        //println(camGoToMin[i]+":"+camBuffer[i]);
        if(camGoToMin[i] && camBuffer[i] == 0) {
          camAngle[i] = camAngle[i] - (PI/512);
        }
        else if(camBuffer[i] == 0){
          camAngle[i] = camAngle[i] + (PI/512);
        }
        image(images,camX[i],camY[i]);
        //lumiereCam[i].display(camX[i]+t, camY[i]+r,false,null,camAngle[i]);
        rayC[i].display(camX[i]+t, camY[i]+r, str(camAngle[i]));

      }
      //Send the current loaded to the client
      if(!compareStrings(loadedLevel,lastLevelLoaded)) {
        dout.println(loadedLevel);
        lastLevelLoaded = loadedLevel;
      }
      dout.flush();
    }
```

Code for the client :

```
    try {
      //request the level loaded by the server
      String level = din.readLine();

      //set up the buttons 
      disableMenus();

      //print the current loaded level on the screen
      printLevel();
      printGuards(true);
      for(int i = 0 ; i < cams.length ; i++) {
        if(cams[i]) {
          while (camAngleMin[i] > camAngleMax[i]) {
            camAngleMin[i] = camAngleMin[i] - 2*PI;
          }
          int t = 0;
          int r = 0;
          int buffer = round(camAngle[i]/(PI/2));
          PImage images;
          if(buffer > 3)
            buffer = 0;
          else if(buffer < 0)
            buffer = 3;
          images = camImage[buffer];
          if(buffer == 0) {
            t = images.width;
            r = 1;
          } else if(buffer == 1) {
            t = images.width/2;
            r = images.height;
          } else if(buffer == 2) {
            t = 0;
            r = 1;
          } else {
            t = images.width/2;
            r = 0;
          }
          if(camAngle[i] > camAngleMax[i] && camBuffer[i] == 0) {
            camGoToMin[i] = true;
            camBuffer[i] = 200;
          } else if(camAngle[i] < camAngleMin[i] && camBuffer[i] == 0) {
            camGoToMin[i] = false;
            camBuffer[i] = 200;
          } else if(camBuffer[i] > 0){
            camBuffer[i]--;
          }
          //println(camGoToMin[i]+":"+camBuffer[i]);
          if(camGoToMin[i] && camBuffer[i] == 0) {
            camAngle[i] = camAngle[i] - (PI/512);
          }
          else if(camBuffer[i] == 0){
            camAngle[i] = camAngle[i] + (PI/512);
          }
          image(images,camX[i],camY[i]);
          //lumiereCam[i].display(camX[i]+t, camY[i]+r,false,null,camAngle[i]);
          rayC[i].display(camX[i]+t, camY[i]+r, str(camAngle[i]));
        }
      }

      //check if the game have to be launched
      if(compareStrings(level,"start")) {
        menu = 11;
      }
      //check if the server's level is already loaded
      else if(!compareStrings(loadedLevel,level) && level != null && level.length() != 0) {
        loadLevelPath(level);
      }
    } catch(SocketException e) {
      menu = -1;
      errorMsg("Le serveur à quitté",Error);
    }
```

Thank you for taking time to reply to my post

Comment: You want to read about async io then. Or you add another thread to your client. One thread reads from the server and pushes data in some queue and the other thread just checks if something is in that queue. But please understand that your question is probably too broad, as there are too many ways to approach this.

Comment: You have to read everything from the server and discard what you don't want.